# How to use the client id for a custom player

Tags: client, soundcloud

I am using the soundcloud API in my custom player, which I also sell. So far I told each client to register a new app and add his own client ID. Is this necessary or can I also include my client ID in the code? I am asking that because of security problems, when other users have my client ID.

Regards,
Rafael

Answer (score 0):

The client_id is usually public and could potentially by reused by somebody else, there is no way to prevent this.

Your case sounds like it's ok to include a general client_id in the custom players instead of one per site.